# View Following Object Java JFrame

Tags: java, view, jframe

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to overcome. What I'm working on right now is a game that just generates an infinite floor of dirt, and I have a player object. I would like to keep the player object in the center of the screen, but move the view. I thought that this would be a common subject, but I haven't been able to find anything related to it on the internet. Do I have to move every other instance and keep the player still to simulate a moving view?
Thank you,
~Guad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you move every other instance except the player.

One way to display a large area of terrain is to use tiles.  A common size for terrain tiles is 256 x 256 pixels.  You create a grid of tiles that's a bit larger than the game area.

Let's say we have an 800 x 600 pixel display area.  This would be completely covered by a 4 x 3 area of tiles.  In order to make the motion smoother, you create a 6 x 5 area of tiles in memory, and display 800 x 600 pixels of the 6 x 5 area.

As the player moves to the right, you add 5 tiles to the right of the 6 x 5 area, and drop the 5 tiles on the left.  On the screen, it looks like the player is covering a great distance, but you're just adding and removing terrain tiles.  You would add and remove tiles in a similar manner when the player moves up, down, and to the left.

I hope this is enough information to get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew that this was a way to do it, although I would have enjoyed the ease of a built-in view system... ah well, this shouldn't be too hard :)